# PHP PDO error successful no matter what

Tags: php

I have a problem with my database! Here is my code:

```
<?php
$host = "/homes/49/jc192699/public_html/dbase";
$database = "EduPro.db";
$dbhandle = new PDO("sqlite:".$host.$database);

if (!$dbhandle){
echo "Error connecting to database.\n";
}

else{
echo "<br>";
echo "<br>";
echo "Database connection successful!";
}

mysql_select_db($database);

?>
```

The problem is that it's saying "Database connection successful!" No matter what I do, if I type the address in wrong, it still says successful, when I renamed the database to a database that doesn't exist, it still says successful. I can't see what the problem is here?

If anybody could help me out it would be GREATLY appreciated!

Thank you!

Comment: Might help: http://www.php.net/manual/en/pdo.error-handling.php

Comment: What's with the `mysql_select_db()` line? You're using PDO, not the MySQL extension

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For starters, the `PDO` constructor throws an exception if there is an error. It does **not** return `false`. Check for errors using

```
try {
    $dbhandle = new PDO("sqlite:".$host.$database);
} catch (PDOException $e) {
    echo 'Connection failed: ' . $e->getMessage();
}
```

Secondly, as you are using SQLite, provided your `dbase` directory is writeable by the script, your connection attempt will create an empty database.

Comment: Ah this would explain why it was creating the databases dynamically on the server. Thank you so much!

Comment: do you mean `PDOException $e` not `PDOException $ex`

Comment: @LawrenceCherone Oops, yes. Corrected

Comment: Seems insane to me that an empty database would be created if one could not be connected to, I'd rather it just throw an Exception and make me aware that it couldn't connect to anything.

Comment: @MikePurcell It's only because SQLite is a single-file DB. The PDO driver allows you to create and build your schema via PHP as well as query it. You would use something like [`file_exists()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.file-exists.php) if you wanted to check for DB existence first

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
<?php
try {
    /*** connect to SQLite database ***/
    $dbh = new PDO("sqlite:/path/to/database.sdb");
    }
catch(PDOException $e)
    {
    /*** real error message prints here ***/
    echo $e->getMessage();
    }
?>
```

This is directly taken from here:
http://www.phpro.org/tutorials/Introduction-to-PHP-PDO.html#4.2